# Python hashlib Checksum is different from linux md5sum

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x

I am trying to calculate the checksum of the string "test" using the python's hashlib module. I am using python3.

```
In [31]: hobj = hashlib.new('md5')
In [32]: hobj.update('test'.encode("UTF-8"))
In [33]: hobj.hexdigest()
Out[33]: '098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6'
```

But when i am trying the same with the linux md5sum the checksum is totally different from the hashlib's output.

```
$ echo 'test' | md5sum 
d8e8fca2dc0f896fd7cb4cb0031ba249  -
```

Is there anything wrong with my python code?

Answer (score 13):

Use `echo -n 'test'` instead. `echo` will output a newline character ("test\n") otherwise.

```
$ echo -n 'test' | md5sum 
098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6  -
```